# Algebra Relacional se puede hacer esta consulta?

Tags: mysql

Fuerte

```
Docente(curpD(PK),nomD,apPatD,apMatD,calleD,cpD,numD,colD,diaD,mesD,añoD)
Materia(idMat(PK),nomMat,horarioMat,numAluIns,curpD(FK))//1:N(Relacion)
```

Mostrar el nombre completo de los Docentes que imparten la materia "**Vectorial**".

Consulta

```
C1<-- π nomD,apPatD,apMatD(σ curpD(Docente) |X| CurpD(Materia) AND nomMat="Vectorial")
```

Mi pregunta es valido hacer la consulta de esta manera, osea si se puede hacer la consula asi??

Comment: Podrias tratar de explicar mejor tu pregunta? usa el boton [edit]

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta está orientada a saber si es válida la consulta o si es óptima? Por otra parte, para ver y entender bien la consulta, sería mejor que lo describieras con palabras, y adicionalmente subieras una imagen donde se pueda apreciar correctamente la forma en que declaras la proyección, la restricción y lo que parece ser un producto cartesiano. En todo caso, lo que intentas es una unión o *JOIN*. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y agrega la información comolementaria. Saludos